# gRrain and Rgraphviz not available in the latest 3.6 R version

Tags: r, package

after updating my R version to 3.6.1 version - the `rGrain` and `rGraphviz` packages do not work. First the error was suggesting that the packages are not writable. However after updating some libraries and trying to source it outside from the BiocManager right now the error appears saying that the compilation fails. Does anybody know how to fix it?

I have already tried multiple options like sourcing it outside and directly from BiocManager and other sources however with no results.

I would appreciate any type of help suggesting how to fix or just install packages `gRain` and `Rgraphviz`.

Comment: What platform are you on? Please provide the output of `sessionInfo()` and the exact errors shown.

Answer (score 0):

Not writable is [biocmanager](https://github.com/Bioconductor/BiocManager/issues/33) being poorly programmed and somehow wanting to install some secondary packages into the main R folder in program files, rather than the usual `R\win-library\` in documents.

You can workaround that by launching the R console or Studio with administrator privileges when installing/updating.